# Int values not marshalling properly between managed and unmanaged code

Tags: .net, interop

I trying to write a simple function to call unmanaged code from managed code.  The data types are int (which should make it even simplier).  The function is this

```
extern "C" MYTEST_API int myTestFunction(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}
```

The managed code looks like

```
    [DllImport("myTest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int myTestFunction(int a, int b);
...
    int p1 = 2;
    int p2 = 3;
    int result = myTestFunction(p1, p2);
    Console.WriteLine("C++ int: " + result);
```

When I run the program, result returns as

```
C++ int: 12977616
```

So, I don't know what's wrong with how I'm declaring or passing the int parameters.  I tried passing the parameters as "Single" and that version worked.

Comment: Properly check your C++ code. Maybe there is something you've missed, as that mapping is right. If Single worked for you - it may be an error in C++ code, as Single and Int a very different in memory, and cannot be mapped one by another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it would have to be something simple and unrelated to fix this...
The C++ .dll wasn't getting updated in Visual Studio even though the content was specified as "Copy Always".  So, it was calling the "float" version of the C++ code with int C# parameters.  Manually refreshing things got it to work.